# How to parse git diff -U output using unidiff parser

Tags: git, parsing, diff, unified-diff

I need hunks (lines added and deleted) with context so I used git diff -u to obtain a diff. I can do *line.is_added* to to obtain *lines_added* but those line will not include lines of context. How do I parse this diff to get *lines_added* and *lines deleted* along with some lines of context. Right now I have

```
  Line 1
  ......
  Line 5 
- Line 6 
+ Line 7
  ......
  Line n
```

Essentially I want

```
lines_deleted = context lines, Line 6, more context lines and 
lines_added = context lines , Line 7, more context lines
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lines_added = []
for hunk in patched_file:
         for line in hunk:
             if line.is_added or line .is_context and line.value.strip() != '':
                 lines_added.append(line.value)
```

and similarly for the lines_deleted. This shall return:

```
  Line 1
  ......
  Line 5  
+ Line 7
  ......
  Line n
```

assuming all lines other than Line 7 are context lines.